# javascript key detection not adding latest character

Tags: javascript, html, string, forms, keycode

so I basically have a function that detects the key that the user presses, and it submits a form whenever the user hits the space bar (don't ask why). Here is my javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        setTimeout("submit()",1);
    }
})
```

so the form submission works, and the fields are sent to the database. there's supposed to be a space in the end of the string that it submitted, obviously because the user hit the space bar to submit, but the `&nbsp;` doesnt show up in the end of the string when it is displayed.

Comment: You could try the `keyup` event. You're going to have to provide more Javascript and the HTML, because I don't see where a `&nbsp;` should be added anywhere. You attached this event to the `document`, so there isn't necessarily a space added to what's submitted. So what exactly is submitted anyways?

Comment: Why would you expect a space to result in `&nbsp;`? They're two completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `keydown` and `keyup` events is that `keydown` fires before adding the pressed letter to the content and `keyup` is fired after it.

If you want the last space to be added too, try binding on `keyup`.

Reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html